# ASP.NET MVC Update part of the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, updatemodel

I have very complex model. The flow is like this:
- in controller I populate the model from the database
- in view I have several tabs. After I fill in the info on the first tab, the second tab enables (this works just fine) and on click on the second tab button I need to update some properties of the model. How can I do this WITHOUT calling the database again in order to populate the model on the controller? The model is very complex, so I can't store as "hidden" all the properties.

I hope I managed to be clear enough. 
Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: I don't really follow the situation, but I'll say this: you update the model and send back everything you need to send back.  If you are updating a partial model, then make a method that can take that partial model to do an update and server back the same/different part of the model (e.g. ViewModels).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situations with ASP.NET MVC. I used ViewBag's for sending the data in very magical ways, created Javascript strings and ran them with Html.Raw, used .executeSql in many places, done real magic. But after all I asked myself: is it worth the pain?

No matter you don't have enough time (i mean this!), I strongly recommend reading some good documents and try some tutorials before diving into the dark sea of work-arounds.

Don't forget, with a good design and using Model class' features well, you won't need work-arounds too much and this will give you, above all, happiness.

For your situation; the best place is to create a Helper class such as:

```
public abstract class Helper<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    private dbContext db = new dbContext();

    public virtual whatEver yourUpdateOperation(int? id, string data)
    {
        // you can do your update operations here
        return whatEver;
    }
}
```

To apply this class to all your WebPages, change the line in your web.config file in your Views directory:

```
<pages pageBaseType="YourProject.HelperDirectory.Helper">
```

From now on you are able to call yourUpdateOperation from your Views such as:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
    <!-- View or operate things-->
    </td>
    @yourUpdateOperation(item.ID, data)
</tr>
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood...I need to call the `yourUpdateOperation` on button click. Like this, is called when the view is first rendered, right...Is the `whatEver` the ComplexModel?

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON object that mimics your model and update it when user clicks on different tab or whatever. When Client-side update/manipulation is done, use AJAX to submit your JSON object to the controller. Here is how you can do this on a button click (you can change it to whatever is clicked):

```
    <script src="../../Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <input type="button" value="Partially Update my Model" onclick="UpdateYourModel()" />
        <input type="button" value="Save to Database" onclick="SaveToDataBase"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Create YourModel Json Object including child objects in it.
             var childObject={"ChildId": "","ChildDescription":""};
//The array name (childObjects) should match the collection name in your actual Model
            var yourModel= { "ModelId": "", "Description": "","childObjects[]":""  }; 


        function UpdateYourModel() {
        //update the childObject first
          childObject.ChildId=1;//any value from anywhere
          childObject.ChildDescription="any value";

        // Update the model
           yourModel.ModelId= $("#ModelId").val();
           yourModel.Description="This property was changed at client side";
           yourModel.childObjects.push(childObject);//add child object to yourModel

        //Likewise, update other properties of yourModel

        }//function ends here

        function SaveToDataBase()
        {
        $.ajax({
                    url: "URL to your controller",
                    data: JSON.stringify(yourModel),
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json;',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                     alert("Success");

                    }
                });
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: But, after calling UpdateComplexModel I need to repopulate the content with both properties of the complexModel and the original Model. I can't mix both...plus, complexModel is called like this just because it is complex...it means it has many properties of (for example) array of other objects. I don't think it's possible to represent it in javascript. I hope I managed to make myself clear

Comment: @SandraS., I just named this model as ComplexModel because you haven't mentioned it's name. Anyway, I have updated my answer to include(represent) array of other objects in JavaScript.